# How deserialize json object of like objects to c# list<T>

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have json response like this:

```
{
  "val1":{
    "id":"1",
    "value":"val"
  },
  "val2":{
    "id":"2",
    "value":"otherVal"
}
}
```

How i deserialize this payload to generic list of SimplyObject where SimplyObject is

```
public class SimpleObject { 
   public int Id {get;set;} 
   public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

When i try to deserialize this payload into List of SimpleObject i have below error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SimpleObject]' because
>   the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object.

Comment: That JSON isn't a list/array type, in fact it's not valid JSON at all.

Comment: Yes, but i want to deserialize him into list))

Comment: It's not valid JSON, you cannot deserialise it at all.

Comment: The json you provided is not valid. Try to validate from [here](http://json2csharp.com/).

Comment: Sorry, i fixed question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deserialise your JSON using a `Dictionary`, for example:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, SimpleObject>>(json);
```

And use it like this for example:

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Item: {item.Key} has Id of {item.Value.Id} and value of {item.Value.Value}");
}
```

Comment: Deleted mine since i answered for the invalid json